# web view does not load google street view properly in javaFx?

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, javafx

I try to open google map on java swing panel by webview. i am using google api in javascript which load Map properly. But problem is that google street view is not loaded properly?Please help me and thanx in advance.

Here is my Javascript code which have google javascript api:-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drawing tools</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- PLUGIN -->
        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.alerts.min.js"></script>
        <link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyArVWbbC4ydx3Cr_JGwZ0ErGojL8OUBotY&libraries=drawing,places"></script>    

        <style>
            /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
             * element that contains the map. */
            #map {
                height: 100%;
            }
            /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .gmnoprint {
                margin: 12px !important;
                height: 26x !important;
            }

            #popup_title {
                font-size: 24px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 1em;
            }

            #popup_container{
                font-size: 16px;  
                width: 450px;
                height: 130px;             
            }
            #popup_content{
                padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
            }

            .gm-svpc{
                left: 12px !important;
                top: 88px !important;  


            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="map"></div>

        <script>
            var marker;
            var markerarrayLatLng = [];
            var map;

            function initMap() {


            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 33.886538, lng: -118.395495},
            zoom: 20,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
            //streetViewControl: false,

            });          

                 }


            initMap();
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

here is my java code which load the script on java panel,
problem is that map is loaded properly but street view does not load images properly.
...

```
public void initMap(final JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group);
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);

        webView = new WebView();

        group.getChildren().add(webView);

        webView.setMinSize(width / 2 + 600, height - 170);
        webView.setMaxSize(width / 2 + 600, height - 170);
        ready = false;
        webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("DrawPath.html").toExternalForm());

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) {
                if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dialog.dispose();
                            ready = true;
                        }
                    });
                    Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();

                    NodeList bodyTags = doc.getElementsByTagName("body");

                    if (bodyTags != null && bodyTags.getLength() > 0) {
                        Node body = bodyTags.item(0);
                        Attr newAttr = doc.createAttribute("style");
                        newAttr.setValue("font-family:  Arial,Roboto");
                        body.getAttributes().setNamedItem(newAttr);
                    }

                    NodeList inputTags = doc.getElementsByTagName("input");

                    if (inputTags != null && inputTags.getLength() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < inputTags.getLength(); i++) {
                            Node body = inputTags.item(i);
                            Attr newAttr = doc.createAttribute("style");
                            newAttr.setValue("font-family:  Arial");
                            body.getAttributes().setNamedItem(newAttr);
                        }
                    }

                } else if (newValue == Worker.State.FAILED) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dialog.dispose();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) {
                if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    doc = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                    doc.setMember("app", PathDraw.this);

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Please let me know how this issue can be resolve?